# SQL Query ( Zend Framework )

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

How can I subtract form the same column if another column is 1 or 2

```
->from('product', array('SUM(weight)')
->where('store = 1')
```

It should always subtract the value in weight if the storage is set to 2.

Comment: If your where conditioni says `storage=1` then you won't ever satisfy the condition of `storage=2`, you realize that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and try this if you can...

```
$selectCounting = $productsTable->select();
$selectCounting ->from('product', 
                       array('SUM(IF(store = 2, 0, weight)) AS `totalweight`', 
                      'product', 
                      'weight'))
                ->where ('1=1')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow it almost worked, for some reason I cant get it to sum up everything. I had to modify it a little to get it to work, got some errors. But this is what i got now;   

$selectCounting = $productsTable->select();
$selectCounting
->from(array('product', ('CASE WHEN store = 2 THEN product = product - weight END AS totalweight'), 
  'product',
  'weight'))
->where ('1=1')

So I don't know if didn't explain very well, but I would like it to sum up the whole column and then subtract the ones marked with store 2.

Comment: Hmm... OK, I gotcha,   I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: @Andy Can you try the updated answer?  I think that might work.

Comment: It didn't work, I think we have to build up query within ZendF, but for now I will just use the numbers if the store = 1. I think I'll just redo the the database for better use later. Thank you so much for all you'r help :-)

Comment: What results did you get?  Error?   Is the field  'store' or 'storage'  you have used both.

Comment: When I try your example i get a syntax error, unexpected 'IF' (T_IF) the field is 'store'

Comment: nevermind, i left off the first paremter of table name.    Try updated code now

Comment: I actually tried that last time, same error ;( I don't know why, I tried to read up on how the query for zend works, but I didn't get any smarter.

Comment: So are you just looking for a single row to be returned?   Can you post the entire function and select statement.  The issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: also the $table needs to be before the array .. so i moved that.. see example image i posted